# Mouse event to record coordinates in image

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, mouse

I am trying to record the coordinate of image whenever a mouse event is occurred. I have two images, my interest is to record the only four coordinates when mouse is clicked for first image and i want to switch to second image and do the same task. I have written code, it works fine for first image but when i switch to second image it doesn't work (whenever mouse is clicked red circle is drawn in that point) or red circle doesn't appear and points also don't get recorded. I want to perform this recording points of two images with single function. I am clueless why this is not working. I have provided the copy of code below. If anyone can help please.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

clicked_points = {0: [], 1: []}  # Dictionary to store points for each image
max_points = 4
circle_radius = 5
current_image = 0
images = ["Left_Img.jpg", "Right_Img.jpg"]

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global clicked_points, current_image
    
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and len(clicked_points[current_image]) < max_points:
        clicked_points[current_image].append((x, y))
        cv2.circle(images[current_image], (x, y), circle_radius, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.imshow("Image", images[current_image])

images = [cv2.imread(image_path) for image_path in images]

cv2.namedWindow("Image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", click_event)

while current_image < len(images):
    cv2.imshow("Image", images[current_image])
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    if key == 27:
        break
    elif key == ord('d'):
        current_image += 1
        if current_image >= len(images):
            break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Left_Img.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYtkk.jpg)

[Right_Img.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBtIF.jpg)

Comment: You have a list called `images` which holds the filenames and a list called `images` which holds the pixel data as Numpy arrays.